# type method not resolved in @Type annotation of hibernate. unable to persist Set of strings in hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, orm, hashset, bytea

We are trying to persist a Set to a column "errors" in postgres db using hibernate.

As per schema definition, bytea is the data type of column "errors"

There is no mapping like onetomany or manytomany are not applicable

We tried to use custom types in hibernate as per https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types. but unable to use this @Type[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3J8X.png)

Spring Boot version 3.0.6
org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core 6.1.7.Final
Postgresql 42.6.0

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Tried
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARBINARY)

Got the exception java.util.HashSet cannot cast to java.utl.arraylist